# Wave Analytics - Fields added through compute expression not available in target dataset

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

I have added a field through Compute expression in Wave analytics dataset. The dataflow ran successfully. But the field is not available in the dataset. Please help with any pointers to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps
Did you enable

> Merge with Source (only if you want all the fields of source node in your output)

now add

> sfdcRegister

function to the end of your compute function then dataset will be created in wave studio

> Note: in saql query of compute function don't enclose your field name within quotes (')